# Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch in matlab why?

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, simulink

I wrote this matlab code to divide an image matrix into smaller matrix of size 787x1000.

in the below code: first i will read an image so I_in=512x512x3, then i change it to binary and reshape it to be (6291456x1), after that i calculated number of frames needed (1 frame = 1000x1) so i will need 787. then i allocate memory to the frame matrix. code will explain steps easily here

```
I_in = imread('aaaa.png');

% encoding image into array of bits
B = de2bi(I_in);
X=reshape(double(B),numel(B),1);
 m= length(B);
 numFrames = floor((m-1)/1000)+1;
 % allocate memory to the frame matrix
 frameData = zeros(numFrames,1000);

for k=1:numFrames
 startAtIdx = (k-1)*1000+1;

 if k~=numFrames
     frameData(k,:) = X(startAtIdx:startAtIdx+1000-1);
 else
     % handle this case separately in case the number of input samples
     % does not divide evenly by the window size
     frameData(k,1:m-startAtIdx+1) = X(startAtIdx:end);
 end

 end
```

when i run this it will it will show me this error :

> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
>
> Error in Untitled1 (line 20)
>            frameData(k,1:m-startAtIdx+1) = X(startAtIdx:end);

i am pretty not really sure that the output i wrote will give me an output of frameData(1x1000).

any body can help in this.

regards

Comment: Print the dimensions of `frameData` and `X` at each step and in the loop and hopefully you will debug your code yourself :) .

Comment: Adding to what Nishant said, you need to check the values of `1:m-startAtIdx+1` and `startAtIdx:end` at each iteration and make sure that they span the same sized ranges. Either use the debugger, or just print them out.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
m = numel(B);
```

instead of

```
m = length(B);
```